# PHP Query return null !impossible

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i post the code and the result, may some one can help..

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
                {
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    echo $login_session_id.$id;
                    include('config.php');
                    set_time_limit(59);
                    $resultEdit = mysql_query($db,"select * from Rubrica where ID_Utente = '$login_session_id' AND ID_Dispositivo='$id' ")or die(mysql_error());;
                    if (!$resultEdit) {
                        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultEdit)==1)
                    {
                        echo 'fatto';
                        while($row = $resultEdit ->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                        echo 'fatto';
                        $id=$row['ID_Dispositivo'];
                        $Username = $row['Username'];
                        $Email= $row['Email'];
                        $Cellulare= $row['Mobile'];
                        $Casa= $row['Home'];
                        $Lavoro= $row['Work'];
                        renderForm($id, $Username, $Email,$Cellulare,$Casa,$Lavoro,$error);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "No results!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Error!';
                }

            }
```

result page:

```
21 18 <---Correct!
```

i try directly the query and i found one row what i want, why here don't go?
i now about the while but i do some test.

All Code ->

```html
<?php
   include('session.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ControlPannel</title>
<!-- jQuery-->
<script src="/web/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<!--theme-style-->
<link href="/web/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<!--//theme-style-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Panello di controllo applicazione" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!--fonts-->
<link rel="icon" href="/web/images/logoB.png">
<!--//fonts-->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
 <!---->
  <div class="header-left">
   <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="/web/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
   </div>
   <div class="top-nav">
    <ul >
     <li><h1>Welcome <?php echo $user_check_email; ?></h1> </li>
     <li class="active" ><a href="" >RUBRICA</a></li>
     <li><a href="Promemoria.php" class="black" > PROMEMORIA</a></li> 
     <li><a href="Sos.php" class="black1"> SOS</a></li>
     <li><a href="imp.php" class="black2" > IMPOSTAZIONI</a></li>
     <li><a href="LogOut.php" class="black2" > LOGOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <p class="footer-class">Template by  <a href="" target="_blank">42Studios</a> </p>
  </div>
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <div class="header-top">
   <div class="logo-in">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="/web/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
   </div>
   <div class="top-nav-in">
   <span class="menu"><img src="/web/images/menu.png" alt=""> </span>
    <ul >
     <li class="active" ><a href="" >RUBRICA</a></li>
     <li><a href="Promemoria.php" class="black" > PROMEMORIA</a></li> 
     <li><a href="Sos.php" class="black1"> SOS</a></li>
     <li><a href="imp.php" class="black2" > IMPOSTAZIONI</a></li>
     <li><a href="LogOut.php" class="black2" > LOGOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
     $("span.menu").click(function(){
      $(".top-nav-in ul").slideToggle(500, function(){
      });
     });
   </script>

   </div>
   <div class="clear"> </div>
  </div>
   <!---->
  <div class="content">
   <div class="Block">
    <?php

     
     function renderForm($id, $Username, $Email,$Cellulare,$Casa,$Lavoro,$error)
     {

      if ($error != '')
      {
       echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
      }
     ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
     <div>
      <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
      <strong>Username: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Username" value="<?php echo $Username; ?>" /><br/>
      <strong>Email: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>" /><br/>
      <strong>Cellulare: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Mobile" value="<?php echo $Cellulare; ?>" /><br/>
      <strong>Casa: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Home" value="<?php echo $Casa; ?>" /><br/>
      <strong>Lavoro: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Work" value="<?php echo $Lavoro; ?>" /><br/>
      <p>* Required</p>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
     </div>
    </form>
    <?php
   }
   include('config.php');
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     echo '1';
     if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
     {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $Username = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Username']));
      $Email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Email']));
      $Cellulare = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Mobile']));
      $Casa= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Home']));
      $Lavoro = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Work']));
      if ($Username == '')
       {
        $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
        renderForm($id, $Username, $Email,$Cellulare,$Casa,$Lavoro,$error);
       }
       else
       {
        // save the data to the databaseRubrica where ID_Utente = '$login_session_id'
        mysql_query($db,"UPDATE Rubrica SET Username='$Username',Mobile='$Cellulare',Home='$Casa',Work='$Lavoro',Email='$Email' WHERE ID_Utente = '$login_session_id' AND ID_Dispositivo='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: RUBRICA.php");
       }
     }
     else
     {
      echo 'Error!';
     }
    }
    else
    { 
     include('config.php');
     if ((isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) && ($_GET['id'] > 0))
     {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      echo $login_session_id.$id;
      set_time_limit(59);
      $resultEdit = mysql_query($db,"select * from Rubrica where ID_Utente = '$login_session_id' AND ID_Dispositivo='$id' ")or die(mysql_error());;
      if (!$resultEdit) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      if(mysqli_num_rows($resultEdit)==1)
      {
       echo 'fatto';
       while($row = $resultEdit ->fetch_assoc())
       {
       echo 'fatto';
       $id=$row['ID_Dispositivo'];
       $Username = $row['Username'];
       $Email= $row['Email'];
       $Cellulare= $row['Mobile'];
       $Casa= $row['Home'];
       $Lavoro= $row['Work'];
       renderForm($id, $Username, $Email,$Cellulare,$Casa,$Lavoro,$error);
       }
      }
      else
      {
       echo "No results!";
      }
     }
     else
     {
      echo 'Error!';
     }

    }
?>
    ///query
    <div id="risultato"></div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="clear"> </div>
  <p class="footer-class-in">Copyright © 2015 Template by  <a href="" target="_blank">42Studios</a> </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Data
[image]
[image]
the select return null

Comment: Could you please explain what issue you are facing?

Comment: select return nothigs

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Some issues that I see directly in your code.

1). All include files should basically be on top of your file. All include and required files should always be at top.

2). Your *if* statement is not correct. You should use `()` for your conditions.

3). The function `mysql_query` accepts parameters in this way :-

```
mysql_query(query, connection)
```

So your final code should be something like this :-

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if ((isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) && ($_GET['id'] > 0))
                {
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    echo $login_session_id.$id;
                    set_time_limit(59);
                    $resultEdit = mysql_query("select * from Rubrica where ID_Utente = '$login_session_id' AND ID_Dispositivo='$id' ", $db)or die(mysql_error());;
                    if (!$resultEdit) {
                        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultEdit)==1)
                    {
                        echo 'fatto';
                        while($row = $resultEdit ->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            echo 'fatto';
                            $id=$row['ID_Dispositivo'];
                            $Username = $row['Username'];
                            $Email= $row['Email'];
                            $Cellulare= $row['Mobile'];
                            $Casa= $row['Home'];
                            $Lavoro= $row['Work'];
                            renderForm($id, $Username, $Email,$Cellulare,$Casa,$Lavoro,$error);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "No results!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Error!';
                }

            }

            ?>
```

Comment: @LorenzoLongiave
Are you getting the variable *id* correctly?

Comment: i try tu put some echo and i see that its seems to block at mysql Query but i do the sam query to the sql and here return one row... @Akshay

Comment: @LorenzoLongiave
You're using `mysql_query` in wrong way. It's used as `mysql_query($query, $connection)` and **not** `mysql_query($connection,$query)`

Answer (score -1):

The problem was i use mysql_query instead mysqli_query.